# Template show <object Object> but no error in observable async pipe

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have observable of todo (id,title,complete)

**TodosCompenent/index.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef} from '@angular/core';
import {Todo, ITodo} from '../../../todo/todo';
import {TodoDataService} from '../../Services/API/todo-data.service';
import {APIService} from '../../Services/API/APIServices';
import {AuthService} from '../../Services/AuthService/auth.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {select, Store} from '@ngrx/store';
import {TodoState} from '../../store/Reducer/todo.reducers';
import {getTodos} from '../../store/selector/todo.selector';
import {getTodoRequest} from '../../store/Actions/todo.action';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todos',
  templateUrl: './index.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.css'],
  providers: [TodoDataService, APIService],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class TodosComponent implements OnInit {


 constructor(private todoDataService: TodoDataService,
             private auth: AuthService,
             private route: Router,
             private ref: ChangeDetectorRef,
             private store: Store<TodoState>
  ) {}
  todo$ = this.store.pipe(select(getTodos));
  public ngOnInit() {
   // this.store.dispatch(getTodoRequest());
  }
  onAddToDo(todo) {
    // this.todoDataService.addTodo(todo).subscribe((newTodo) => {
    //   this.todos = this.todos.concat(newTodo);
    //   // this.fetchTodo();
    // });
  }
  // onToggleTodoComplete(todo) {
  //   this.todoDataService.onToggleComplete(todo).subscribe((updatedTodo) => {
  //     todo = updatedTodo;
  //     // this.fetchTodo();
  //   });
  // }
  // onRemoveTodo(todo) {
  //   this.todoDataService.deleteTodo(todo.id).subscribe((_) => {
  //     this.todos.filter((t) => t.id !== todo.id);
  //     // this.fetchTodo();
  //   });
  // }
  // fetchTodo() {
  //   this.todoDataService.getTodos().subscribe((todos) => {
  //     this.todos = todos;
  //   });
  // }
  signOut() {
    this.auth.signOut();
    this.route.navigate(['/index']);
  }

}
```

this one is use async pipe but not working still show **[object Object]** in template

```
<app-todo-list _ngcontent-adf-c193="" _nghost-adf-c190="" ng-reflect-todos="[object Object]"><div _ngcontent-adf-c190="" class="view ng-star-inserted"> No Todo at the moment </div>
</app-todo-list>
```

the data that in the store

```
{
  todo: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'stay home',
      complete: true
    },
    {
      title: 'test',
      complete: true,
      id: 2
    },
    {
      title: 'demo',
      complete: true,
      id: 3
    }
  ],
  type: 'GET_TODO_SUCCESS'
}
```

**TodosCompenent/index.html**

```
  <app-todo-list-header (add)="onAddToDo($event)"></app-todo-list-header>
  <div *ngIf="(todo$ | async) as todos">
  <app-todo-list
    [todos]="todos"
    (toggleComplete)="onToggleTodoComplete($event)"
    (remove)="onRemoveTodo($event)"
  ></app-todo-list>
  <app-todo-list-footer [todos]="todo$ | async"></app-todo-list-footer>
  <div fxLayoutAlign="center center" >
    <button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="signOut()">Logout</button>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I use app state to select the todos.

**todo.seletor.ts**

```
import {createFeatureSelector, createSelector} from '@ngrx/store';
import {TodoState, selectAll, selectTotal} from '../Reducer/todo.reducers';
import {ITodo} from '../../../todo/todo';

export  interface AppState {
  todos: ITodo[];
}
export const selectorName = 'todos';
export const getTodoState = createFeatureSelector<TodoState>(selectorName);
// export const getTodoState = createSelector(todoFeatureSelector, state => state.entities);

export const todoCount = selectTotal;
// @ts-ignore
export const getTodos = createSelector(getTodoState, (state: AppState) => state.todos );
// export const getTodos = createSelector(getTodoState, selectAll );

// export const getTodoCount = createSelector(getTodoState, todoCount);
```

I use ngrx/enntity in the reducer state.

**todo.reducer.ts**

```
import { ITodo, Todo } from '../../../todo/todo';
import { EntityAdapter, EntityState } from '@ngrx/entity/src/models';
import { createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import {todoActions} from '../Actions/todo.action';
import {Action, createReducer, on, State} from '@ngrx/store';

export interface TodoState extends EntityState<ITodo> {
  error: string;
  message: string;
}

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<Todo> = createEntityAdapter<ITodo>();

export const initialTodoState: TodoState = adapter.getInitialState({
  error: null,
  message: null
});

export const todoReducer = createReducer(
  initialTodoState,
  on(todoActions.getTodoRequest, (state, action) => {
      return adapter.removeAll({...state, error: null});
    }
  ),
  on(todoActions.getTodoFailure, (state, action) => {
    return {...state, error: action.payload};
  }),
  on(todoActions.getTodoSuccess, (state, action) => {
    return adapter.setAll(action.todo, {...state});
  }),
  on(todoActions.addTodoSuccess, (state, action) => {
    return adapter.addOne(action.payload, {...state, error: null});
  }),
  on(todoActions.updateTodoRequest, (state, action) => {
    return adapter.updateOne(action.update, {...state, error: null});
  }),
  on(todoActions.updateTodoSuccess, (state, action) => {
    return adapter.addOne(action.payload, {...state, error: null});
  }),
  on(todoActions.updateTodoFailure, (state, action) => ({...state, error: action.payload})
  ),
  on(todoActions.deleteTodoRequest, (state, action) => {
      return adapter.removeOne(action.todoID, {...state, error: null, message: null});
    }
  ),
  on(todoActions.deleteTodoSuccess, (state, action) => {
    return {...state, error: null, message: action.message};
  }),
  on(todoActions.deleteTodoFailure, (state, action) => {
    return {...state, error: action.payload, message: null};
  })
);

export const {
  selectAll,
  selectIds,
  selectTotal,
  selectEntities
} = adapter.getSelectors();
```

I have tried but these are not working for me. I've been struggling with this problem long time.

```
<div *ngIf="user$ | async; let user">
  <h3> {{user.name}}
</div>
```

```
<div *ngIf="(primitive$ | async) || ' '; let primitive">
  <h3> {{primitive}}
</div>
```

```
<div *ngIf="(user$ | async) || {}; let user">
  <h3> {{user?.name}}
</div>
```

**TodoListComponent/index.ts**

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {ITodo, Todo} from '../../../todo/todo';
import {select, Store} from '@ngrx/store';
import {TodoState} from '../../store/Reducer/todo.reducers';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-list',
  templateUrl: './index.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todoList.component.css'],
})
export class TodoListComponent {
  @Input()
  todos: ITodo[];

  @Output()
  remove: EventEmitter<Todo> = new EventEmitter();

  @Output()
  toggleComplete: EventEmitter<Todo> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    private store: Store<TodoState>
  ) {}
// todoCount = this.store.pipe(select(getTodoCount));
  onToggleTodoComplete(todo: Todo) {
    this.toggleComplete.emit(todo);

  }
  onRemoveTodo(todo: Todo) {
    this.remove.emit(todo);

  }
}
```

**TodoListComponent/index.html**

```
  <div *ngIf="!(todoCount | async)" class="view" style=";">
    No Todo at the moment
  </div>

<section class="main" *ngIf="(todoCount | async) > 0">
  <ul class="todo-list">
    <li *ngFor="let todo of todos" [class.completed]="todo.complete">
      <app-todo-list-item
        [todo]="todo"
        (toggleComplete)="onToggleTodoComplete($event)"
        (remove)="onRemoveTodo($event)"
      ></app-todo-list-item>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

**TodoListItemComponents/index.html**

```
<div class="view">
  <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <div fxFlex="50%">
      <mat-checkbox
        (click)="onToggleTodoComplete(todo)"
        [checked]="todo.complete"
        [style]="todo.complete?'text-decoration: line-through':''"
        color="primary"
        >{{todo?.title}}</mat-checkbox
      >
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="20%" style="padding: 5px;">
      <button
        mat-flat-button
        style="
          background-color: #dc3545;
          border-color: #dc3545;
          width: 20px;
          min-width: 36px;
        "
        class="destroy"
        (click)="onRemoveTodo(todo)"
      >
        <span style="color: white;">
          X
        </span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div fxFlex="20%" style="padding: 5px;">
      <button
        mat-flat-button
        style="
          background-color: #dc3545;
          border-color: #dc3545;
          width: 20px;
          min-width: 36px;
        "
        class="destroy"
        (click)="editTodo(todo.id)"
      >
        <app-edit-icon style="position:relative;right:10px;top:4px" ></app-edit-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TodoListItemComponents/index.ts**

```
import {
  ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef,
  Component,
  EventEmitter,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
  OnInit,
  Output
} from '@angular/core';
import {ITodo, Todo} from '../../../../../todo/todo';
import { TodoDataService } from '../../../../Services/API/todo-data.service';
import { UpdateTodoModalComponent } from '../update-todo-modal/update-todo-modal.component';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo-list-item',
  templateUrl: './index.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default

})
export class TodoListItemComponent implements OnInit {
  bsModalRef: BsModalRef;
  @Input()
  todo: ITodo;
  todos: ITodo[];

  @Output()
  remove: EventEmitter<Todo> = new EventEmitter();

  @Output()
  toggleComplete: EventEmitter<Todo> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(
    private todoDataService: TodoDataService,
    private bsModalService: BsModalService,
    private ref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getTodoList();
  }

  editTodo(todoId: number) {
    const initialState = {
      data: this.todos,
      id: todoId,
      ignoreBackdropClick: true,
      animated: true,
      keyboard: true,
    };
    this.bsModalRef = this.bsModalService.show(UpdateTodoModalComponent, {
      initialState,
    });
    this.bsModalRef.content.event.subscribe((result) => {
      if (result === 'Ok') {
        // this.getTodoList();
      }
    });
  }
  getTodoList() {
      this.todoDataService.getTodos().subscribe((todos) => {
        this.todos = todos;
        this.ref.detectChanges();
      });
  }
  onToggleTodoComplete(todo: Todo) {
    this.toggleComplete.emit(todo);
  }
  onRemoveTodo(todo: Todo) {
    this.remove.emit(todo);
  }
}
```

I expect the list should display the data as 
the page show no data

[image]

Comment: sorry, not very familiar with that type of syntax. is there a reason you are not using *ngFor?

Comment: Which part is giving that output? Is that the `TodosCompenent/index.html`? Which part exactly? You have two child components there too. Please specify which part exactly is resulting in that output.

Comment: @Rick i use *ngfor in app-todo-list

Comment: @ulmas   
<app-todo-list-item
        [todo]="[object] [object]"
   ></app-todo-list-item>

Comment: What are you expecting to see in the template? You did pass an object to the Todo List component so it showing you the correct value.

Comment: I'm still not sure where that output is. Also, the output you indicated in the subject (`<object Object>`) is different from `<app-todo-list-item [todo]="[object] [object]" ></app-todo-list-item> `. Maybe you have two issues. I would suggest posting a stackblitz if you can. But generally this happens when you project the whole object onto the template instead of the individual key values.

Comment: edited the description

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't check generated html, it won't bring light on the issue.

`*ngIf="todo$ | async as todos"` is the right way to fetch data in a template.

If you don't see todos you need to debug your store to ensure that it has expected state and reduces actions correctly.

The best way to do it is to use [store-devtools](https://ngrx.io/guide/store-devtools/install).

With its help you can browse the store and to find the answer.

First check that an action really adds todos to the store. When it works and you see desired state check how selectors work. You have commented code like `getTodos = createSelector(getTodoState, selectAll )` - it's the right way to use ngrx/entity.

If store has data but selector doesn't fetch it you can use `tap(console.log)` in different places to check what selector has, for example:

```js
todo$ = this.store.pipe(select(getTodos), tap(console.log));
```

now we can see in the console returned data.